# Objective-C .mm in initializer and class factory method

Tags: objective-c, factory

This is a question related to Objective-C memory management.

On the [About Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) page there are some examples

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
   NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                  self.firstName, self.lastName] autorelease];
   return string;
}
```

and the second one

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", 
                                  self.firstName, self.lastName];
   return string;
}
```

The only difference is that in the first example an initializer is called, and in the second a class factory method.

Basic memory management rules section is said that after an `alloc` call I will own the object I allocated. So in the first example I allocate an object and at the same time initialize it. In this I own the object and have to `release` it. In the second example I don’t. But doesn’t the factory method `stringWithFormat:` do the same thing in one call, I mean allocating the object and initializing it?

So the main question is, why don’t I have to release the object in the second example?
are there any special memory management rules when implementing a class factory method?

Comment: p.s. all of this is basically moot with the introduction of ARC. You would probably be better off reading up on that. Under ARC, you simply ignore things like retain, release, autorelease (attempting to call those methods will result in a compile error) and know that everything will just work.

Comment: The answers are basically right except they state that the object returned from the class factory method is autoreleased.  The important thing is that you don't own it and don't have the right or responsibility to release it.  It may *or may not* be autoreleased as such. There may be a completely different memory management scheme going on. It may return a singleton. It may return a permanent shared value object (like `NSNumber` keeping a common instance for all requests for a 0-valued number object). Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, a class factory method will return an object that is in the autorelease pool. It has done the alloc, init, autorelease for you, just like in the first example. Unless you retain it, when the pool is drained, it will be released.

Comment: So by convention a class factory method has to do autorelease also, when implemented?

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you didn't create the string. You only create objects by invoking methods that begin with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`.

You may take ownership, if you like, by invoking `retain`, but then you're also responsible for invoking `release`. In this example, there's no need. You don't need the string any more. What the caller does with it is their responsibility.

When invoking a factory method like this, you typically receive an autoreleased object. But you don't really need to think about that. Because *you* didn't create it (because *you* didn't use a method beginning with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` to get that string), all you need to do is think about the retain count delta -- do you need to retain it to keep it from disappearing from underneath you. Since it's just being returned to the caller, the answer in this example is no.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the factory method internally calls the `alloc`, and thus returns retained object, but it adds that object to the nearest [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI), so when that pool will be drained, the object will be released.